# Stop iOS7 zoom in webview

Tags: javascript, ios, css, webview, media-queries

I have looked at other questions similar to this and they do not ask the exact question that I need to ask!

**Question:** How do I stop WebView from zooming in on an input field **AND** still respond to css media queries.

The reason for the last part is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

When I use this meta tag, notice the `width=device-width` and `height=device-height`. This is good because it stops the zooming on the WebView on my iPad.

However, with this, my css queries stop working! My css is:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts */
  #wrap{width:768px;height:1024px;background-color:#FFF;border:1px solid gray;position:relative;}
  form{width:380px;overflow:hidden;padding-top:30px; padding-left: 40px;}
  .results{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;background-color:#FFF;height:100%;float:right;color:#000;display:none;}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts */
  #wrap{width:1024px !important;height:768px;background-color:#FFF;border:1px solid gray;position:relative;margin:0 auto;}
  form{width:511px;overflow:hidden;padding-top:30px; padding-left: 106px;}

}
```

As you can see, the top query is portrait and the bottom landscape. When I have the meta tag in, it will only load the portrait version (no matter how what orientation the iPad). This is because the meta tag is setting the height and width.

If I take away the `width=device-width` and `height=device-height` in the meta tag, then the css works again, but then the zooming in on inputs when focus also does.

I had tried some JavaScript fixes but I actually got a better result with the zooming using the simple meta tag, but I am open to a JavaScript fix also.

Comment: If you want it not to zoom, wouldn't you set user-scalable=no?

Comment: Ah, should have mentioned that. When in WebView, that rule is completely over ruled. @RichardDoyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Plus, why are you adding such constrained widths on your elements? By that point, you should maybe look in to [responsive design](http://csswizardry.com/2013/02/responsive-grid-systems-a-solution/).

Comment: I didn't want to use responsive design because I didn't want a 'grid' system and didn't want all the bulk of a css file. It's also only for iPads so no need to create media queries for everything when I only need 2.

Comment: Also, this method messes up the view in landscape view.

Comment: So by this point, shouldn't it be fluid? If you're constraining, you risk the potential of it working across all iPads and not just the one you have, unless you have them all (or iOS simulator.) :D And you only need one media query to work for all selectors. In fact you don't need any, if you're strictly building it for the iPad. Percentages would work great too, then you wouldn't need to worry about landscape/portrait rotation. :) Anyway, answer is there. It __should__ work.

Comment: Thanks for your views. Yeah maybe I should reconsider the method in the way I style it. Also, yes, this works in the normal safari browser. However, for some reason in webview, this is completely over-written. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Ah, strange. It should. No worries, just I thought maybe a wrapping element could have say, `width: 80%; margin: auto;` and you instantly have a centered container that would remove half of the time and code you'd need to write. Plus you wouldn't need orientation by this point. Percentages are much, much more scale-friendly for devices and you wouldn't even need to bother with orientation media queries :) Hope this helps!

Comment: I've accepted as part of your answer was telling me to look into responsive design. I guess I'll have to take this route! Thanks for helping! :-)

Comment: Thank you dude, appreciate it. You would't need a whole branch of CSS for the responsive method, just a simple wrapper and have all your elements in a few layouts. So like, 1/2, 1/3 and 1-whole grids. That's 50%, 33.33% and 100% with float left applied. Simple. No need to fear the over engineering of grids! Any time buddy. :-)